# Run cherrypy example on openshift

Tags: import, openshift, wsgi, cherrypy

So, I have a python 2.6 + cherrypy app on openshift. [Their example](https://github.com/penguinforge/openshift-cherrypy) application uses the cherrypy WSGI server ,that I know nothing about, with the cherrypy framework, but I would like to run the standart cherrypy server instead, like shown in the example on the [cherrypy website](http://www.cherrypy.org/), which doesn't work (says "Permission denied"). Any ideas?

I know that it is really easy to convert a standart cherrypy app into a WSGI app, but still.

EDIT: Yes, I would like to use both: the cherrypy framework and the cherrypy server

Also, you know how you can use import to import .py files in the same dir? that also doesn't work, so I'm wondering if that's an openshift-specific thing, not possible with python 2.6, or just me missing something.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to use just the cherrypy wsgi server or the cherrypy framework and server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a read of:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/01/using-alternative-wsgi-servers-with.html

You can supply an `app.py` file to override the use of default Apache/mod_wsgi.